# GIT Log show only recent entries

Tags: git

I am trying to utilize cmd prompt to get the last 10 commits with the author, commit hash, and description to utilize in a form. I have been experimenting with `git log --pretty=short`, however, the output seems to go forever.

I would like to know how to reduce the amount of commits returned to the last 10 commits utilizing the `git log` command.  I plan on extracting the information into a data structure for later use.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Run:

```
git log -n <number-of-commits> --pretty=short
```

For all options, see:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Answer (score 6):

The following command will display the last 10 commits:

```
git log -n 10 --pretty=short
```